# new instance of listview confused please explain

Tags: vb.net

Hello everyone I am a fairly new VB.NET student.  I am working with a listview object for the first time.  I found bits and pieces of code to make this work.  Basically I want to add info to the second column and the first column.  This code works fine but I am having a hard time trying to understand why it works.  Can someone explain it to me please?

I don't understand why the dim itm as new listview is needed.  Why can I not just do listview.subitems.add...   I know there is no command for this but why?  Why do I need to create a new instance of listview to fill the second column.

```
Private Sub btnAddItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddItem.Click
    Dim itm As New ListViewItem  'Add items to listbox
    itm = lstData.Items.Add(txtInput.Text) 'Add data from txtbox
    itm.SubItems.Add(txtInput.Text) ' Add data from txtbox
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't understand because the code is wrong.  Remove "New".  And delete that comment.  And think a while about the difference between a ListView and a ListViewItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I don't understand why the dim itm as new listview is needed`  its not, you are creating a new `ListViewItem` to add to the LV.

the ListView contains objects - ListViewItems, Groups and Columns with the last 2 controlling how things are displayed.  It is the `ListViewItem` which contains `SubItems` (LV.Items is a collection of `ListViewItems`, while SubItems is a collection of `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem`.)

`Why can I not just do listview.subitems.add`  Because the LV would have no idea which Item to associate the new SubItem with (ie which row to display it on).

```
itm.SubItems.Add(txtInput.Text)
```

This creates a new SubItem on the fly.  If you want to set more than just the text, you can instance a `ListViewItemSubItem` to set other properties (ForeColor, Name, Font, Tag...)

An important thing to know is that it is not a Grid - you can easily edit the Label/Item text, but not the Subitem text (inline).  Rather than a Grid, look at Explorer for an example in use - you can edit the FileName (==Item), but not the size, date, etc etc etc. (== SubItems)

Comment: I guess what I am trying to figure out or better understand is why can you not add items to the listview like you can a listbox?  I understand listview vs. listviewitem but why can I listbox.item.add("") but cannot listview.item.add and or listview.subitems.add

Comment: The short answer is because it is not a simple ListBox.  Your way, the LV would have no idea what "row" to display the new SubItem on.  SubItems get displayed as columns for a given ListViewItem (Details View), so subs are added to ListViewItems (also, you do not have to have the same number of subs for each item!).

Comment: What is the proper syntax to add a 3rd or 4th column to the LV? And how to add data specifically in those columns?

Comment: just add 3 or 4 sub items - you dont add to a specific "column" (cols are just how it is displayed). So you'd add 3 or 4 subitems - you can't add to col 4 without a 3 there, add them in the order you want them displayed. To access them: `myLV.Items(X).SubItems(3).Text = "foo"` where X is the index of the row/item.  or: `myLV.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text = "Bar"`

Answer (score 0):

Listview.items.add(...).subitems.add(...).subitems.add(...)