# Populate second listview with data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a listview control 'lvRequests which populates data from an access db. I can then retrieve a value from a row and storing it in a variable: 'item'.

What I am trying to do is, populate listview1 with item. I have tried various ways but keep running into problems. Can someone show hot to me populate a second listview. Many thanks

```
Dim item As String

    If Not lvRequests.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then '// check if item is selected.
        With lvRequests.SelectedItems.Item(0)

            item = .SubItems(2).Text
            MessageBox.Show(item)


        End With

    End If
```

Comment: ListViews are populated with ListViewItem objects, not strings.  All your code does is assign the text from a SubItem to a string.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456429/1070452

Comment: Thank you. I shall try to research further.